# Bash script print output in json format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to curl a webpage and does some processing to it and in final i am trying to print in json format.(which actually needs to be in mongodb input)

so the input (which is read though curl) is

**Input:**

```
brendan google engineer
stones microsoft chief_engineer
david facebook tester
```

for the kind of processing, i'm assigning values to the variables ($name, $emloyer, $designation)

my final command which converts to json is,

```
echo [{\"Name\":\"$name\"},{\"Employer\":\"$employer\"},{\"dDesignation\":\"$designation\"}]
```

**The current output is,**

```
[{"Name":"brendan","Employer":"google","Designation":"engineer"}]
[{"Name":"stones","Employer":"microsoft","Designation":"chief_engineer"}]
[{"Name":"david","Employer":"facebook","Designation":"tester"}]
```

but, i want the output in the same line separated by comma and square brackets in the start and end (not on every lines)

**Expected output:**

```
  [{"Name":"brendan","Employer":"google","Designation":"engineer"},{"Name":"stones","Employer":"microsoft","Designation":"chief_engineer"},
    {"Name":"david","Employer":"facebook","Designation":"tester"}]
```

any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you care where the linebreaks are if you're generating JSON? You should care about what the parse tree and the document model look like -- if you need to care about what kind of whitespace is between the elements, your consumers (whoever's parsing the code you generate) are Doing It Wrong.

Comment: ...in particular, MongoDB *definitely* doesn't care whether you have newlines or spaces outside of syntactically-pertinent locations (such as string contents).

Answer (score 8):

Conventional text-processing tools can't do this right for the general case. There are a bunch of corner cases to JSON -- nonprintable and high-Unicode characters (and quotes) need to be escaped, for instance. Use a tool that's actually built for the job, such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

---

```
jq -n -R '
[
  inputs |
  split(" ") |
  { "Name": .[0], "Employer": .[1], "Designation": .[2] }
]' <<EOF
brendan google engineer
stones microsoft chief_engineer
david facebook tester
EOF
```

...emits as output:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "brendan",
    "Employer": "google",
    "Designation": "engineer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "stones",
    "Employer": "microsoft",
    "Designation": "chief_engineer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "david",
    "Employer": "facebook",
    "Designation": "tester"
  }
]
```

Comment: Perfecto!! Had you gotten another choice, what tool you would've suggested?

Comment: If installing jq isn't an option, my usual fallback is embedding a snippet of Python, since there's an excellent json module in the standard library there.

Comment: I though about perl, but then jq is being more available with unices these days, i guess. Anyways, nice answer ++

Comment: Very helpful, first time hearing about JQ, can the input be given from curl? coz I'm doing some processing to the curl file and also adding few more variables which are apart from curl.

Comment: Curl writes to standard output, and `jq` read from standard input; so yes, just replace the here document with a pipe from `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
sep='['
curl "...whatever..." |
while read -r name employer designation; do
    printf '%s{"Name": "%s", "Employer": "%s", "Designation": "%s"}' "$sep" "$name" "$employer" "$designation"
    sep=', '
done
printf ']\n'
```

I do agree that this is brittle and error-prone; if you can use a JSON-aware tool like `jq`, by all means do that instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy indeed, typed that without thinking - fixed now, thanks for diagnosing!

Comment: @tripleee This actually works out pretty well, can the same be written as mongodb query?

it would be like 

db.testcollection.insert([{"Name": "brendan","Employer": "google","Designation": "engineer"},{"Name": "stones","Employer": "microsoft","Designation": "chief_engineer"}])

Comment: No idea where you want that to go. If you just want it added to the text we print, the change should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to jq 1.5 or later, then you can use `inputs` and may wish to consider using `splits(" +")` in case the tokens might be separated by more than one space:

```
jq -n -R '
  [inputs
   | [splits(" +")]
   | { "Name": .[0], "Employer": .[1], "Designation": .[2] }]'
```

If you do not have ready access to jq 1.5 or later, then please note that the following will work with jq 1.4:

```
jq -R -s '
  [split("\n")[]
   | select(length>0)
   | split(" ")
   | { "Name": .[0], "Employer": .[1], "Designation": .[2] }]'
```